# Submitting Ajax Form With SimpleModal (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I have a form within a SimpleModal modal, but when I try to use serialize with jQuery, the form data is always blank.  The form serialize works outside of the modal, so theres something preventing the serialize from grabbing the form data.  This is the code I am using:

```
<div id="address_form" style="display:none">
  <div id="contact-area">
    <form id="address_form" action="submit" method="POST">
      <label for="Street">Street:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Street" id="street" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-button" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

$("#address_form").submit(function(){
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  alert(data)
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two elements with the id of `address_form`. Change the id on the DIV with that id and it will work.